# How to get a component type in Angular 2 (related to DynamicComponentLoader )

Tags: angular

How do I get a "Type" for a component to pass it to:

```
loadIntoLocation(type: Type, hostLocation: ElementRef, anchorName: string)
```

I want to pass the Type via **@Input** of the child:

```
<searchComponent [componentToLoad]="component"></searchComponent>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a type to a variable:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dyn-cmp',
  template: `
`})
class DynCmp {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-cmp',
  template: `
<searchComponent [componentToLoad]="dynCmp"></searchComponent>
`})
class ParentCmp {
  dynCmp:Type = DynCmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I couldn't figure it out, because I didn't have the import {Type}!

Comment: `Type` can be omitted.