# Angular2: call a component from a json string

Tags: angular

let say i have a variable in a component, `MyVar`.

I want to give to this variable a component type:

```
 MyVar = MyComponentType.
```

`MyComponentType` comes from a `Json` String or a simple String 'MyComponentType'.
How can i do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for a similar question.

Comment: What do you mean by a "variable in a component". Do you mean a property? If I understand what you are trying to do, the usual approach is to write a "factory".

Comment: [How to get a component type in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411267/how-to-get-a-component-type-in-angular-2-related-to-dynamiccomponentloader)
 | [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Comment: 'MyComponentType' is a string comming from a Json.I already have a component Named  MyComponentType. I try to find a solution to give to the ngComponentOutlet a component witch the name is the same as the 'MyComponentType' . I don't know witch value will come from the Json so i have to transfom the Json string 'MyComponentType to a an exisiting component MyComponentType and then bind it to the ngComponentOutlet. Thank you